StateHasChanged is not re rendering component
I am using blazor server side for one of my project , petty new to me . I am stuck at very first screen, the login screen.
Below is my razor component html
<div class="row vh-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4 bg-white rounded p-4 shadow">
    <div class="row justify-content-center mb-4">
        <img src="Images/AQuity.png" class="w-50 h-50" />
    </div>
    <form>
        <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="email" style="text-align:left" class="form-label label-left w-100">Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="email" @bind=@_credential.Email />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-4">
            <label for="password" style="text-align:left" class="form-label label-left w-100">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="password" @bind=@_credential.Password />
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm w-100" @onclick=Authenticate>Login</button>
    </form>
    <p class="mb-0 mt-2 text-center">Forgot Password? <a href="#" class="text-decoration-none">Reset Now!</a></p>
    @if (!_result.Success)
    {
        <p class="text-danger">@msg</p>
    }
</div>

my code behind partial class
    public partial class Login
 {
     [Inject]
     protected IAuthenticateService _authenticateService { get; set; }
     [Inject]
     protected NavigationManager Navigation { get; set; } = default!;
     private Credential _credential { get; set; } = new Credential();
     private ResultSet _result { get; set; } = new ResultSet();
     public string msg = string.Empty;
     private void Authenticate()
     {
         _result = _authenticateService.Authenticate(_credential);
         if (_result.Success)
         {
             Navigation.NavigateTo("");
         }
         else
         {
             msg = "new error !";
             this.StateHasChanged();
         }
     }
 }

On below method
    private void Authenticate()
{
    _result = _authenticateService.Authenticate(_credential);
    if (_result.Success)
    {
        Navigation.NavigateTo("");
    }
    else
    {
        msg = "new error !";
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }
}

in else block if _result.Success is false it will contain a error message in msg field
and that is set to display on html part as
    @if (!_result.Success)
{
    <p class="text-danger">@msg</p>
}

But even after calling this.StateHasChanged(); , that component is not re rendering.
How to achieve this in blazor ? on failed login to show msg on component
This is server side blazor on .net 8.0

Where is Interactivty set?  Do you hit breakpoints in Authenticate?

Interactivity set in app.razor 
<Routes @rendermode=RenderMode.InteractiveServer />


@MrCakaShaunCurtis To clarify , everything is working here except the else part of Authenticate() ; value of msg get filled in else part and StateHasChanged() was called, it should display that msg value on component view

Based on the information you've provided, I can't reproduce your problem.
I've taken you code and produced a simple MRE:
@page "/"

<h3>Test</h3>

<button class="btn btn-warning" @onclick=Authenticate>Login</button>

@if (!_result.Success)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger m-3">@msg</div>
}

@code {
    [Inject] protected NavigationManager Navigation { get; set; } = default!;
    private string msg = string.Empty;
    private Result _result = new(true);

    // It's likely your real Authenticate is async
    private Task Authenticate()
    {
        _result = new(false);

        if (_result.Success)
            Navigation.NavigateTo("/Counter");

        else
            msg = "new error !";

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public record Result(bool Success);
}

Click the button and you get:


Thanks, I solved it. The problem was right there in front of eyes, I had to use  and all the events started to work

can you post your html to as a MRE ?? I will try my hands on that too
